# Why is using Power Pivot getting the Data Model deleted in Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery, powerpivot, excel-2016

I am using Power Pivot to do some analysis and then make Pivot tables from the data model. There are more then 1 interconnected tables. The tables have been created using Power Query. The relationships are created using Power Pivot.

After my work is done and the Excel File is closed, the data model gets deleted. I can see that as the file size gets reduced. Also when I open the file and try to modify the pivot tables receive the following message: " the connection for this pivot table has been Deleted". The queries that were created using power query do not refresh either (Shows: Download Failed).
When I open the Power Pivot for Excel window, it does not show any tables in it.

I am using Microsoft Professional Plus 2016. Already Repaired MS Office.

Would really appreciate if any one can help.

Thank you.

Comment: What Excel file format are you using when saving the file?

Comment: I am saving it in .xlsx format.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this problem is caused because of Power Pivot Crashes. Found this blog https://exceleratorbi.com.au/does-the-power-pivot-excel-add-in-crash-for-you/, followed the steps and that seems to solve my problem for now. Its interesting that this problem is there since long and Microsoft has not been able to solve it yet.